# Iterating/Paging REST API with Biztalk Send Port- Best Practice?

Tags: json, rest, biztalk, biztalk-2016

There is a REST API I need to pull from and each response has a 100 record limit (300k+ total records). I'm trying to think about what the best practice might be with paging/iterating via BizTalk adapter(s). FYI, this is complicated by the fact that I have 10 or so endpoints I need to page through and have to use a custom pipeline (for each to convert to XML and specify a namespace since a JSON response is the only type available).

The main question for me is how to manage the paging and multiple endpoints efficiently. The page number and offset are in the JSON response so my first guess is I'd have to build an orchestration to analyze the response and create the new request from it. I know there are a lot of ways to do this so I'm curious what best practice dictates and what the most efficient way would be.

- Can I somehow get away with NOT using an orchestration?
- Can/should I make use of a dynamic send port?

Comment: Shouldn't whatever is requesting the information be asking for the next page or records?  If you are trying to get BizTalk to request all 300k+ records sequentially, then you are going to face a lot of issues (rate limitations on the web service, possibly throttling in BizTalk). Doing mass data transfer via BizTalk are always problematic.   As it stands your question is a bit broad in my opinion.  Can you add more details as to what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: This situation is highly impractical.  If the endpoint has 300k records and is limited to 100 per call, then there was never the expectation that anyone would try to retrieve all of them.  Have you triple confirmed that this is the only way?

Comment: So this is more a proof of concept, we are considering implementing BizTalk in our organization and this was one of the functions I was asked to try. I think MGMT just wants to know what, if any, limitations BizTalk has. I suppose I will just create an orchestration that will construct a request to the send port using mapped variables and apply query conditions so that only a few pages at most have to be iterated through.